# Run multiple SQL statements concurrently within a single session in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have written a stored procedure which makes use of two temporary tables and in the final select statement the computed temp tables will be used.

Below is the structure of my sproc :-

```
   -- Statement 1
   INSERT INTO #temp1(Col1,Col2) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM TABLE1  -- This takes ~7 sec

   -- Statement 2
   INSERT INTO #temp2(Col1,Col2) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM TABLE2  -- This takes ~15 sec

   -- Statement 3
   SELECT A,B,C FROM Table3                                    -- This takes ~10 sec
   JOIN #temp1...
   JOIN #temp2...
```

When I execute the sproc it takes around 32 sec (7+ 15 + 10 sec) roughly to complete, is there a way in which I could run statements 1 & 2 parallelly (there is no dependency between statements 1&2) which could benefit the overall execution time.

Please let me know if I need to be more clear about this.

Comment: This is not where I would start looking for performance improvement. The first thing I would do is look at the execution plan and try to find the time consuming part of the stored procedure there. Also, are you sure you need the temporary tables?

Comment: We had tried multiple approaches and brought down the execution time from 2 min down to ~30 sec, few of my senior colleagues went through the code and nothing major can be done in terms of query optimization

Comment: and yes, the temp tables were created against a logic we had using cte.. temp tables worked better compared to subquery and apply operator

Comment: Well, then, I hope this can be done. As far as I know you can use [query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017) to force parallelism on a specific statement, I'm not sure if it's possible to force two different statement to run in parallel.

Comment: The only way to execute different queries in parallel is with separate sessions. This could be orchestrated in T-SQL with a Service Broker solution but that would be a bit complex and you would need to use permanent tables rather than temp tables due to the different sessions. It would probably be easier to do that in the application layer.